# Convert DateTime in mm/dd/yyyy to DateTime in yyyy-dd-mm

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert from a `DateTime` in `MM/dd/yyyy` to another `DateTime` in `yyyy-dd-MM`

I was able to get a `string` in form `yyyy-dd-MM` by using `Date.Parse().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

But when I use `Convert.ToDateTime()` or `Date.Parse()` to convert the `string` back to a `DateTime`, it just converted the `string` back to `DateTime` form `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: The DateTime depends on the Current System formatting.

Comment: DateTime is actually a double, it's not "stored" in any format. If you want to view it in a specific format, that's what ToString is for.

Comment: [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

Comment: You should know saying *I want to convert date time in some format to date time to some other format* is technically wrong because the date time has no format and it's the string representation of date time that has format. To be able parse custom formats, you should use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) . So to convert a string in `yyyy-dd-MM` to `DateTime` you should use `var d = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-31-12", "yyyy-dd-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and you can pass suitable culture or let it to be `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: I really don't think this question deserves the downvoting it is getting, it is based on a simple misunderstanding of how c# stores and uses the `DateTime` class, but it is an understandable misunderstanding

Comment: Formats are for how we display dates to users, perhaps in different cultures.  A Date is simply a *value* and has no format....and cannot be foirmatted.  This is a very, very good thing or else we would have to know what culture a date came from in order to "unformat" it or read it.

Comment: @AndyWiesendanger - internally, it's actually [using a unsigned 64-bit integer](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,138), not a double.  but other than that your point is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying *I want to convert date time in some format to date time to some other format is technically wrong* because the format is about string representation of `DateTime`.

**Why can't I convert a string in `yyyy-dd-MM` format to `DateTime` using `DateTime.Parse()`?**

- The [`DateTime.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx) parses a date and time string by using the conventions of the current culture.
- To parse a date and time string in a custom/fixed format across machine and possibly cultural boundaries, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

So to convert a string in `yyyy-dd-MM` to `DateTime` you can use:

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact("2016-31-12", "yyyy-dd-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also as mentioned in MSDN, because the string representation of a date and time must conform to a recognized pattern, you should always use exception handling when calling the parse method to parse user input or consider using `TryParse` or `TryParseExact`.

**More Information:**

- [DateTime.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#Tasks)

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between forms of representation of `DateTime`. Actually, `DateTime` is a number of ticks and can be represented in any form you want.

According to your answer - if you need to stringify `DateTime` with certain format - you should specify format that you want wherever it needed.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the DateTime always shows date in the format of your system. That is, if you set your system format to yyyy-dd-MM, it will show date in that format.

If you have to display date on ui, better use formated string as you have done.

But if you want to perform any operation (weather comparession or any other), use DateTime. All the DateTime will always be in system's format.

Comment: It's more than just the system format.  The system format can *influence* the default culture, but one can quite easily use a different culture.