# How can i format a substring string variable to my local time and then create a directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void CreateCountryDateTimeDirectories(List<string> urls)
{
    //48
    // 12
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count(); i++)
    {
        string pathDateTime = urls[i].Substring(48, 12);
    }
}
```

First iteration for example in pathDateTime:

201701122100 if i will split it to date and time: year 2017 month 01 day 12 hours 21 minutes 00

So i want to format it some how in a string to my local time format in this case Israel. Not to change it to my local time but to format it as date time like it's formatting in my country.

And then to format also the last item:

201701122300

After formatting both the first and last items i want to create a directory on the hard disk in this format:

This is example of the date and time in Israel and this is how i want the directory to be created:

[12-01-2017_21:00---12-01-2017_2300]

Or maybe some other format maybe something nicer ? But the idea is to create a directory of the date and time range.

Comment: [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Tried this but it's not working it's never get inside the if: DateTime dt;
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(pathDateTime.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))

Comment: Tried also: string format = "yyyyMMdd HH:mm";
                CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(pathDateTime, format, null); and other ways all of them throw exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: `var d = DateTime.ParseExact("201701122100", "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: You're welcome :) You can read more about [Custom Date and Time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also you may like [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34537141/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CreateCountryDateTimeDirectories(List<string> urls)
{
    //48
    // 12
    var lowDate = null;
    var highDate = null;
    var thisDate = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < urls.Count(); i++)
    {
        string pathDateTime = urls[i].Substring(48, 12);
        thisDate = DateTime.ParseExact(pathDateTime, "yyyyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        if (lowDate == null) lowDate = thisDate;
        if (highDate == null) highDate = thisDate;
        if (thisDate < lowDate) lowDate = thisDate;
        if (thisDate > highDate) highDate = thisDate;
    }
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory($"{lowDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HH:mm")}---{highDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HH:mm")});
}
```

Keep coding!